# Invoking remote powershell command not returning all results

Tags: powershell, invoke

I'm pretty new to powershell and I'm trying to invoke a remote powershell command to return the size of a drive but am having trouble.

If I run the below command directly on the server, then I get a result of 4.

```
import-module virtualmachinemanager
$checks = get-vm -Name DC1 | get-scvmcheckpoint
foreach ($disk in $checks){
$disk.virtualdiskdrives.virtualharddisks.size
}
```

I then try to run the command remotely using the below, but I don't get a result. The $checks variable contains a number of other values though.

```
 $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName VM01 -ConfigurationName     Microsoft.Powershell32 -Credential administrator
    $checks = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList VM01 -ScriptBlock {
    import-module virtualmachinemanager
    get-vm -Name DC1 | get-scvmcheckpoint
}

foreach ($disk in $checks){
$disk.virtualdiskdrives.virtualharddisks.size
}
```

Comment: This will be one of your problems `-Credential administrator` the -Credential parameter should be a valid PScredential object

Comment: Hi Jan, I don't follow. When I execute the command it prompts me for credentials. It automatically has the username populated as "administrator" and I just enter the password. I don't see how that is a problem as the script executes. If I display the results of $checks, I can see there are values in there. But for some reason, not the "virtualdiskdrives.virtualharddisks.size".

Comment: Don't worry, forgot you can just supply a username and get prompted. Although ".\Administrator" might be a better choice. What do you get in the $checks variable?

Comment: I've been using PowerGUI so I can sift through the variable results, and there is quite a lot in $checks variable. If I expand it, I can see under SyncRoot\1\VirtualDiskDrives but there is no "virtualharddisks" under that. There is however another SyncRoot which has a value of "System.Object". Doesn't mean much to me though. I'll try and put up a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely issue here, (haven't tested the code on actual VMM server) is that objects returned from remote session are Serialized and De-serialized. Here is a reference [How objects are sent to and from remote sessions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/).

To get around this, I would suggest doing all the processing on a remote machine and only return simple PS objects.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName VM01 -ConfigurationName     Microsoft.Powershell32 -Credential administrator
$checks = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList VM01 -ScriptBlock {
    import-module virtualmachinemanager
    $disks = get-vm -Name DC1 | get-scvmcheckpoint
    foreach ($disk in $disks){
        $disk.virtualdiskdrives.virtualharddisks.size
    }
}

foreach ($disk in $checks){
    write-host "Disk size = $disk"
}
```

Comment: Ah got ya, excellent! That did it and also provided me a good lesson. Thanks Jan!